# address sanitize runtime error in iOS device

Tags: ios, address-sanitizer

in xCode7 build setting tap, i add flag as below:

```
other c flags: -fsanitize=address
other linker flags:-fsanitize=address
```

It works well on the simulator, but when I run the app on an iOS device, it  crashes.
The error information is:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/6DFB6F58-A283-4F82-A4B5-903E12B7D0CA/EduLayout.app/EduLayout
>   Reason: image not found。

so how to fix it？

Comment: Are you enabling the sanitizer in your scheme? : http://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-the-address-sanitizer.html

Comment: could i ues this feature without use xcode schem. because i want to complie code  without xcode IDE.

Comment: ok - but does it work when you build via the scheme in the IDE? if it does, you can use the build output as a working example.